# Sync home directory with Vagrant

Tags: virtualbox, sync, vagrant

I'm using the [ubuntu/xenial64](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/hashicorp/boxes/precise64) Vagrant box.

When I `vagrant up` with the default Vagrantfile I'm able to log in and get to work without needing to input a password via `vagrant ssh`.

I land in the home directory by default:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~$ pwd
/home/ubuntu
```

I'd like to be able to have my `/home/ubuntu` directory synced with the project root on my host machine (like the `/vagrant` directory is).

I read up in the [docs](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/basic_usage.html) and added the following to my Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/home/ubuntu"
```

Now I'm being asked for a password which I don't want. Also I tried "vagrant" and "ubuntu" for the password and wasn't able to log in anyways.

- How do I sync my `/home/ubuntu` directory in my Vagrant box with my host project root while still not being required to input a password?

Note: My current workaround is to continue working from `/vagrant` in my Vagrant box.

Comment: Does your linked question address forwarding the `/home/ubuntu` directory to the host project root?

Comment: The linked question appears to address why you can't.